# Cant install the postgresql gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

> `$ sudo gem install pg Building native extensions.  This could take a
>   while... ERROR:  Error installing pg:     ERROR: Failed to build gem
>   native extension.`
>
> ```
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
> ```
>
> extconf.rb checking for pg_config... no No pg_config... trying anyway.
>   If building fails, please try again with 
>   --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config checking for libpq-fe.h... no Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>
> ```
>     --with-opt-dir
>     --without-opt-dir
>   --with-opt-include
>   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>   --with-opt-lib
>   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>   --with-make-prog
>   --without-make-prog
>   --srcdir=.
>   --curdir
>   --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
>   --with-pg
>   --without-pg
>   --with-pg-config
>   --without-pg-config
>   --with-pg_config
>   --without-pg_config
>   --with-pg-dir
>   --without-pg-dir
>   --with-pg-include
>   --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
>   --with-pg-lib
>   --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}
> ```
>
> / Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection. Results logged
>   to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.1/ext/gem_make.out

Comment: have you installed PostreSQL before installing the gem? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Detailed_installation_guides

Answer (score 2):

In the error message, it specifically states `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.` This most likely means that you don't have the 'native' extension installed, which is the PostgreSQL actual software.

This is because the native extension is required to run the gem, as the gem is only a ruby wrapper for the actual database software. Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Detailed_installation_guides) for how to install Postgres.